# Changing the colour depending on date difference - React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm trying to display a different colour depending on the amount of days between 2 dates. I've successfully got my differences between the two dates to work, but i'm struggling with updating the colour as it doesn't update straight away as my 'diff' doesn't update.
Should I be doing this in a different way? I've tried using the useEffect hook to try and sequence them but its given me errors.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
const ColourDisplay = ({ date }) => {
    const [colour, setColour] = useState("green")
    const [plantDate, setPlantDate] = useState(new Date(date))

    const [diff, setDiff] = useState(0)

    let colourPicker = () => {
        if (diff <= 0) {
            setColour('red')
        } else if (diff > 0 && diff <= 2) {
            setColour('orange')
        } else {
            setColour('green')
        }
    }

    let diffCalculator = () => {
        const today = new Date()
        const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        const utc1 = Date.UTC(plantDate.getFullYear(), plantDate.getMonth(), plantDate.getDate());
        const utc2 = Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

        setDiff(Math.floor((utc1 - utc2) / _MS_PER_DAY))
        
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setPlantDate(new Date(date))
        diffCalculator(colourPicker)
    }, [date])

    if (date) {
        return <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${colour}` }}>color</div>
    }
}
export default ColourDisplay
```

If anyone can help me out with what i'm doing wrong here then that would be amazing.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have updated the code**

You have used several useless states, one state is enough to show the result.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as React from "react";

const ColourDisplay = ({ date }) => {
  const [colour, setColour] = useState("green");

  let colourPicker = (diff) => {
    if (diff <= 0) {
      setColour("red");
    } else if (diff > 0 && diff <= 2) {
      setColour("orange");
    } else {
      setColour("green");
    }
  };

  let diffCalculator = (plantDate) => {
    const today = new Date();
    const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    const utc1 = Date.UTC(
      plantDate.getFullYear(),
      plantDate.getMonth(),
      plantDate.getDate()
    );
    const utc2 = Date.UTC(
      today.getFullYear(),
      today.getMonth(),
      today.getDate()
    );
    colourPicker(Math.floor((utc1 - utc2) / _MS_PER_DAY));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    diffCalculator(new Date(date));
  }, [date]);

  if (date) {
    return <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${colour}` }}>color</div>;
  }
};
export default ColourDisplay;
```

Comment: Yes I can see I added some unnecessary ones now, thank you for this.